# Touchstart vs Click. What happens under the hood?

Tags: javascript, cordova

First, excuse me please, this is not a programming question, but I think it wont fit to [Theoretical CS](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), and [CS Non Programming](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science) is still in private Beta.

after updating my phonegap Applications to listen to

> $(selector).bind("touchstart",function());

instead of

> $(selector).click(function());

(here with jquery),and the performance improved remarkably, I want to know what touchstart does different, despite of the fact that it is probably designed especially for mobile devices environments. I looked up the [w3c document](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-touch-events-20110505/#the-touchstart---------event) on touchstart, but it doesnt provide any information.

if anyone has a link to further explanation or can explain how it works, I greatly appreciate it

Comment: I think `touchstart` is similar to `mousedown`, so the event will be fired quicker.

Comment: alex, thanks for the idea. I tested mousedown in my application, but the performance is similar to .click.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

On the iPhone the `touchstart` event fires as soon as your finger touches the screen, whereas the `click` event fires 300 ms after you touch the screen and lift you finger off the screen. The 300 ms time delay is so that Safari can wait to see if you intend to double tap the screen in succession to simulate the zoom gesture.

Comment: Depending on circumstances, you may enjoy the Fastclick.js library: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Comment: This is a good explanation but which is a preferred method? Thanks.