# the difference between mouseDown and mousePress javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When does the mouseUp and mouse press launch and what is the difference between them?
Does using mouseDown and mouseUp mean holding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between 'mouseup' and 'click' events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805225/whats-the-difference-between-mouseup-and-click-events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mouseDown detects when the mouse is pressed down.  mousePress detects when the mouse is pressed down then released.  mouseUp detects when the mouse is up.

Comment: Is there an event for holding element(drop drag)?

Comment: I don't believe so