# onTouchStart vs onClick in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I was building a project, I found that component worked way I was intended when I double clicked it button that using **onClick**. But when I changed onClick to **onTouchStart**, it starts to work I intended.

But I am bit worried using this without not knowing the difference with **onClick** method.

Is there a specific case that I should use **onTouchStart** instead **onClick** in React.js?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633297/touchstart-vs-click-what-happens-under-the-hood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnTouchStart` is an event for devices with digitizer(touch devices).
`OnClick` is an event for click (mouse) or tap (digitizer devices).

Open this Codepen on a mobile device and on desktop: http://codepen.io/blixt/pen/pgvGdK.

You will experience that the slide works in mobile but not in desktop.

You can achieve the same experience on desktop using mouse events: `mouseup`, `mousedown` and `mousemove`.

Answer (score 2):

`onTouchStart` start is a **touch** event which fires when the user touches the element.

`onClick` is a  **mouse** event which fires when user clicks on the element.

Touch event only work for touch screens, although there are ways to bind `touch` events with `onClick` events.